# Redirect after number of clicks

Tags: ruby, logic, elixir

I have bunch of URLs. I need to share these urls with some people.
I need to convert these urls into new urls such that:=> after 5 clicks on each URL they should redirect to the login page.

e.g. `www.abc.com/m` => `www.abc.com/m1234` (this one we share) => after 5 clicks => login page.

Note: `www.abc.com/m` requires login. `www.abc.com/m1234` doesn't require login for 5 attempts and it opens `www.abc.com/m`.

I need to solve this problem with elixir/ruby.
Is there any way to do it without including DB?

What's the best approach to do it?

Comment: You need to persist data somewhere on the server, and the best way to do that is some kind of database. There's really no way around this.

Comment: @tadman How about saving each new url (m1234) and then having a count column for that url ?

Comment: That's one solution, but it requires a database to store those counts. If you want something cheap and easy, try a counter using [Redis](http://redis.io) as a back-end. That way you can set a TTL on your counts if these should expire after a period of time.

Comment: Hmm....well it's like for forever until the url has been visited 5 times. But redis seems to be a nice option. Though I have no idea how complex it will be!

Comment: If it's a much longer-term thing, at the very least you need a SQLite database, or for more active systems, PostgreSQL or MySQL.

Comment: We use PostgreSQL. I thought about starting with number (5) and then decrementing it. Then on each request checking this url column and it's corresponding count. As soon as it hits 0 we redirect to login page.

Comment: You probably want to start with zero and increment to N, that way if you change your limit in the future you can always raise the threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what your stack is as you tagged both elixir and ruby but one solution would be to use the [Agent](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Agent.html) module. Another solution is to use an [ETS/DETS Table](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/ets.html)

This is essentially a GenServer wrapper around state and would be perfect for something like this.

Basically, depending on your stack you would send a message to an elixir/phoenix application that has an agent running.

For example:

```
#lib/appname.ex

  def start(_type, _args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec, warn: false

    children = [
      worker(AppName.ClickCounter.start_link, [])
    ]

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Test.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
```

The above starts the Agent once the application starts and in the event of a fail or crash will restart the agent.

Then in your `MyApp.ClickCounter` module:

```
defmodule MyApp.ClickCounter do

  @doc """
  Starts the Agent and registers it's process id under the name of the module name. Initializes it's state as an empty map.
  """
  def start_link do
    Agent.start_link(fn -> %{} end, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  @doc """
  Takes in a string url and increments it's click count by one.

  If there is no counter for the url already it will create one with a default value of 0.
  """
  def increment_counter(url), do: update_state(url)

  @doc """
  Returns the current value of the counter for the given url
  """
  def get_counter(url), do: Agent.get(__MODULE__, &(Map.fetch!(&1, url)))

  defp update_state(value) do
    Agent.update(__MODULE__, fn(state) -> 
     Map.update(state, value, 1, fn(count) -> 
      count + 1
     end)
    end)
  end
end
```

Then fire up a `iex -S mix` console and have a play with it.

```
iex(1)> MyApp.ClickCounter.increment_counter("http://google.com/123")
:ok
iex(2)> MyApp.ClickCounter.get_counter("http://google.com/123")
1
iex(3)> MyApp.ClickCounter.increment_counter("http://google.com/123")
:ok
iex(4)> MyApp.ClickCounter.increment_counter("http://google.com/123")
:ok
iex(5)> MyApp.ClickCounter.increment_counter("http://google.com/123")
:ok
iex(6)> MyApp.ClickCounter.get_counter("http://google.com/123")
4
```

As you can see from the above you can apply whatever logic you want to the update, retrieval methods. Since this is stored in a process as well it is pretty darn fast.

If this needed to be persistable you could use something like ETS's/DETS instead which can persist the tables to disk and upon restart/crash load the existing data.

Another way to persist could be to have a database and then have a process worker (simple way is to use a `GenServer` and have it implement `Process.send_after(x,x, 1000ms)` sort of thing) which goes through the state and persists it to the data base again allowing you to recover from a crash.